# session timeout at IDP with spring security saml

Tags: spring, security, saml, spring-saml

Can someone please explain what happens at the SP sessions,  when a timeout occurs at the IDP ?

How does the SP know to redirect user to IDP to login again ?

Does the SP ping the IDP every time a request comes to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Once the user is transferred to the IdP, the session length is up to the SP. There isn't a mechanism really "built-in" to SAML,  beyond the SP deciding that it needs to get a more recent authentication.